# Python Scipy interpolate warning message

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to fit a spline surface to some 2D data using scipy interpolate

```
from scipy import interpolate
```

Using

```
 # fit spline to surface
 xnew, ynew = np.mgrid[x[0]:x[-1]:100j, y[0]:y[-1]:100j]
 tck = interpolate.bisplrep(X, Z, array)
 znew = interpolate.bisplev(xnew[:,0], ynew[0,:], tck)
```

But I'm getting the following warning messages:

> C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate_fitpack_impl.py:975:
>   RuntimeWarning: A theoretically impossible result when finding a
>   smoothing spline with fp = s. Probable causes: s too small or badly
>   chosen eps. (abs(fp-s)/s>0.001)
>           kx,ky=3,3 nx,ny=16,18 m=610 fp=18417275715.663498 s=575.071502   warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(_iermess2[ierm][0] + _mess))
>   C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate_fitpack_impl.py:975:
>   RuntimeWarning: The required storage space exceeds the available
>   storage space. Probable causes: nxest or nyest too small or s is too
>   small. (fp>s)
>           kx,ky=3,3 nx,ny=20,20 m=610 fp=661.198585 s=575.071502   warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(_iermess2[ierm][0] + _mess))
>   C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate_fitpack_impl.py:975:
>   RuntimeWarning: The required storage space exceeds the available
>   storage space. Probable causes: nxest or nyest too small or s is too
>   small. (fp>s)
>           kx,ky=3,3 nx,ny=20,20 m=610 fp=1013.605606 s=575.071502   warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(_iermess2[ierm][0] + _mess))

And instead of getting something similar to my data:
[image: sample data]

I'm getting this:[image: spline output]

I admit I don't know what the warning messages mean and haven't found anything on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like your input data contains too few data points? Another issue might be that your `x` and `y` axes have very different order of magnitude. I don't know if that is a problem for `bisplrep`, but other interpolation algorithms do not like that.

I had more success with [`scipy.interpolate.Rbf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html#scipy.interpolate.Rbf), which also gives a very smooth result.